# Provided that we add an axiom □□(p=>p) to S1, how can we prove the rule of necessitation?

Tags: modal-logic

Since we don't have N, we can't use DR1, DR2, DR3 because they were all derived from N. In system K, K was an axiom, so we can't use K either without proving it first.
Here are the axioms and transformation rules for S1:

[image]
[image]

We can't use any theorems of K because we don't have K or N. So how do we prove N here?

Answer (score 1):

I shall give a proof sketch hoping that you would find it quite appealing to intuition and steering clear of the usual tricky steps:

You have already

[image]

and it is done for theorems of propositional logic.

You can prove its converse by *reductio ad absurdum*:

[image]

Hence, all the S1-theorems with necessity prefix are constructed by theorems of propositional logic. For those, you have

[image]

that is,

[image]

and the substitution rules.